# Why are there differences between GPArotation::Varimax and stats::varimax?

Tags: r, rotation, pca, psych

There are (at least) two different ways to varimax-rotate a loadings matrix in R, `GPArotation::Varimax` and `stats::varimax`.

Oddly, even if the Kaiser-Normalization is enabled for both, they yield subtly different results.

That's a bit of a pain for testing.

```
library(GPArotation)
library(psych)
data("Thurstone")

principal.unrotated <- principal(r = Thurstone, nfactors = 4, rotate = "none")  # find unrotated PCs first
loa <- unclass(principal.unrotated$loadings)

varimax.stats <- stats::varimax(x = loa, normalize = TRUE)
varimax.GPA <- GPArotation::Varimax(L = loa, normalize = TRUE)

unclass(varimax.stats$loadings) - unclass(varimax.GPA$loadings)  #  small differences
#>                           PC1           PC2          PC3           PC4
#> Sentences       -6.158219e-05  1.978395e-05 2.507685e-04 -1.901896e-06
#> Vocabulary      -5.381439e-05  2.066220e-05 2.507735e-04  8.781259e-06
#> Sent.Completion -5.209981e-05  2.127085e-05 2.469213e-04  4.052756e-06
#> First.Letters   -1.096117e-04 -1.206990e-06 1.043846e-04  3.892283e-05
#> 4.Letter.Words  -1.272682e-04 -6.622974e-06 9.323033e-05  2.852347e-05
#> Suffixes        -3.135108e-05 -7.443932e-06 1.258813e-04  6.922436e-05
#> Letter.Series   -1.960431e-04 -5.694846e-05 1.031590e-04 -5.951437e-05
#> Pedigrees       -8.587490e-05 -6.325140e-05 1.779604e-04 -1.750454e-05
#> Letter.Group    -2.335317e-04 -3.802961e-05 6.190849e-05 -6.346030e-05
varimax.stats$rotmat - varimax.GPA$Th  # small differences
#>               [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
#> [1,] -1.380279e-04 -1.380042e-05  2.214319e-04  2.279170e-06
#> [2,] -9.631517e-05 -2.391296e-05 -1.531723e-04  3.371868e-05
#> [3,] -1.758299e-04 -7.917460e-05 -6.788867e-05 -1.099072e-04
#> [4,]  9.548010e-05 -6.500162e-05  1.679753e-05  5.213475e-05
```

Granted, those differences are not huge – but they seem to be too large to be just floating point artefacts.

I thought varimax was a well-defined automatic rotation that should yield *precisely* the same result.

Are these differences expected behavior?

How can they be explained?

Notice that `normalize = TRUE` is set for *both*, and so the (absence of) Kaiser normalization *does not* account for the differences (thought it accounts for [those from within `psych::principal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351780/why-are-there-differences-in-psychprincipal-between-varimax-and-varimax)).

Comment: This question is more about statistical methods. [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) is suited for such a question.

Comment: mmh, I see.
Isn't this very much about the technical *implementation* of varimax, though? If I understand it correctly, the results *should* be the same, but (for supposedly technical R-ish reasons), they're not.

Comment: I think it is a matter of implementation.

Comment: and would you say a matter of technical implementation is better suited for Cross Validated or Stack Overflow?
I would've thought SO, but I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: I think this is due to different implementations in stats::varimax and GPArotation::Varimax. Requiring high precision by setting `eps=1e-15` exhibits, that GPArotation needs much more time for the process (1000 iterations and more - but the results agree), while setting `eps=1e-5` GPArotation gives already the more accurate result. Possibly the eps-parameter is simply differently understood for the stop-criterion in the iterations. For the late reader: see also my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37322261/629177