# Why are there differences in psych::principal between "Varimax" and "varimax"?

Tags: r, matrix, pca, psych

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350891/why-are-there-differences-between-gparotationvarimax-and-statsvarimax), I have asked why there are differences between `stats::varimax` and `GPArotation::Varimax`, both of which `psych::principal` calls, depending on the option set for `rotate =`.

The differences between these two (see other question) account for some, but not all of the differences from `psych::principal`.
It appears that these differences somehow get *exacerbated* by `psych::principal`.
(I have a simple theory why, and I'd like to get that confirmed).

```
library(GPArotation)
library(psych)
data("Thurstone")

principal.unrotated <- principal(r = Thurstone, nfactors = 4, rotate = "none")  # find unrotated PCs first
loa <- unclass(principal.unrotated$loadings)

# just to compare that the rot.mat is correct
varimax.stats <- stats::varimax(x = loa, normalize = TRUE)
varimax.GPA <- GPArotation::Varimax(L = loa, normalize = TRUE)
# notice we're here NOT interested in the difference between stats and GPA, that's the other question

diff.from.rot.meth <- unclass(varimax.stats$loadings - varimax.GPA$loadings)  # very small differences, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350891/why-are-there-differences-between-gparotationvarimax-and-statsvarimax
mean(abs(diff.from.rot.meth))
#> [1] 8.036863e-05

principal.varimax.stats <- principal(r = Thurstone, nfactors = 4, rotate = "varimax")
principal.Varimax.GPA <- principal(r = Thurstone, nfactors = 4, rotate = "Varimax")

diff.from.princ <- principal.Varimax.GPA$rot.mat - principal.varimax.stats$rot.mat  # quite a substantial change, because Theta is NOT a rotmat, that makes sense
mean(abs(diff.from.princ))
#> [1] 0.021233

mean(abs(diff.from.rot.meth)) - mean(abs(diff.from.princ))  # principal has MUCH bigger differences
#> [1] -0.02115263
```

This seems way too big for just a floating point artefact or something.

My hypothesis would be that the (additional) difference stems from the fact that **`GPArotation::Varimax` defaults to (Kaiser) `normalize == FALSE`, whereas **`stats::varimax` defaults to (Kaiser) `normalize == TRUE`**, which *cannot* be set differently from within `principal::psych``.

`stats::varimax` manual:

> `## varimax with normalize = TRUE is the default`

`GPArotation::Varimax` / `GPArotation::GPForth` manual:

> The argument normalize gives an indication of if and how any normalization should be done before rotation, and then undone after rotation. If normalize is FALSE (the default) no normalization is done. If normalize is TRUE then Kaiser normalization is done. (So squared row entries of normalized A sum to 1.0. This is sometimes called Horst normalization.)

Also, they `psych::Kaiser` manual warns:

> The GPArotation package does not (by default) normalize, nor does the fa function. Then, to make it more confusing, varimax in stats does,Varimax in GPArotation does not.

Can anyone confirm that the difference is, in fact, accounted for by the normalization options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of different loadings occurs because of different accuracy in the procedures *(of course, since in psych::principal the `normalize` option is not evaluated, all the other procedures must used with that option switched to TRUE)*. While the accuracy in stats::varimax and GPArotation::Varimax can be configured (parameter `eps`) this is ignored in psych::principal, and seems to be implicitely equal to stats::varimax with eps=1e-5 .

If we increase accuracy in stats::varimax and GPArotations::Varimax to `eps=1e-15` then we get the same result (at least up to 8 digits)  as in a concurring implementation in my MatMate-program which I've tested to be very accurately equal to the SPSS computations too.

The missing handling of the explicite option `eps` in psych::principal seems to be a bug, and its poor implicite default value is surely unsatisfying.

Interestingly, the GPArotation::Varimax needs very many rotations with `eps=1e-15`, see the output at the end; so either there is another internal procedure implemented or the eps-parameter is evaluated differently in the decision when the iterations can be stopped. One example, see at the end of this answer, might suggest such an effect.

Below the protocol of the comparision; only the first two rows of the loadings are displayed.

```
The first three computations with low accuracy (eps=1e-5) 
all procedures give equal or comparable results, 
except GPArotation, which is already near the exact answer
--------------------------------
>  principal(r = Thurstone, nfactors = 4, rotate = "varimax")$loadings    *1000000
>  stats::varimax(x = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-5)$loadings            *1000000
>  GPArotation::Varimax(L = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-5)$loadings      *1000000

The second three computations with (attempted) high accuracy (eps=1e-15) 
all procedures except psych::principal give equal results, and they
agree also with external crosscheck using MatMate
--------------------------------
>  principal(r = Thurstone, nfactors = 4, rotate = "varimax",eps=1e-15)$loadings*1000000
>  stats::varimax(x = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-15)$loadings*1000000
>  GPArotation::Varimax(L = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-10)$loadings*1000000
```

The attempts to little/default accurate results with large `eps` or without

```
# ===== Numerical documentation (only first two rows are displayed)================
> principal(r = Thurstone, nfactors = 4, rotate = "varimax")$loadings*1000000
                RC1       RC2       RC3       RC4      
Sentences       871655.72 216638.46 198427.07 175202.57
Vocabulary      855609.28 294166.99 153181.45 180525.99


> stats::varimax(x = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-5)$loadings         *1000000
                PC1       PC2       PC3       PC4      
Sentences       871655.72 216638.46 198427.07 175202.57
Vocabulary      855609.28 294166.99 153181.45 180525.99

> GPArotation::Varimax(L = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-5)$loadings   *1000000
                     PC1      PC2      PC3       PC4
Sentences       871717.3 216618.7 198176.3 175204.47
Vocabulary      855663.1 294146.3 152930.7 180517.21
# =============================================================================
```

Now the attempts to more accurate results with smaller `eps`

```
> principal(r = Thurstone, nfactors = 4, rotate = "varimax",eps=1e-15)$loadings  *1000000
                RC1       RC2       RC3       RC4      
Sentences       871655.72 216638.46 198427.07 175202.57
Vocabulary      855609.28 294166.99 153181.45 180525.99

> stats::varimax(x = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-15)$loadings                   *1000000
                PC1       PC2       PC3       PC4      
Sentences       871716.83 216619.69 198174.31 175207.86
Vocabulary      855662.58 294147.47 152928.77 180519.37

> GPArotation::Varimax(L = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-10)$loadings             *1000000
                     PC1      PC2       PC3       PC4
Sentences       871716.8 216619.7 198174.31 175207.86
Vocabulary      855662.6 294147.5 152928.77 180519.37

Warnmeldung:
In GPForth(L, Tmat = Tmat, method = "varimax", normalize = normalize,  :
  convergence not obtained in GPForth. 1000 iterations used.

# Result by MatMate: --------------------------------------------------------
 lad = cholesky(Thurstone) 
 pc = rot(lad,"pca")
 pc4 = pc[*,1..4]                           // arrive at the first four pc's
     t = gettrans( normzl(pc4),"varimax")   // get rotation-matrix for row-normalized pc's
 vmx = pc4 * t                              // rotate pc4 by rotation-matrix 
 display = vmx     * 1000000
                     PC1      PC2       PC3       PC4
Sentences       871716.83    216619.68   198174.31   175207.87
Vocabulary      855662.58    294147.46   152928.77   180519.37


# ===============================================================================>
```

A much better matching of the results by stats::varimax and GPArotation::Varimax could be achieved by setting eps to 1e-12 in stat:: and to 1e-6 in GPArotation , where one value is the square of the other. We get then

```
> GPArotation::Varimax(L = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-6)$loadings*1000000
                     PC1      PC2       PC3       PC4
Sentences       871716.8 216619.8 198174.49 175207.63
Vocabulary      855662.5 294147.6 152928.94 180519.21

> stats::varimax(x = loa, normalize = TRUE,eps=1e-12)$loadings*1000000
                PC1       PC2       PC3       PC4      
Sentences       871716.80 216619.74 198174.40 175207.85
Vocabulary      855662.55 294147.52 152928.86 180519.36
```

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to confirm that applying `psych::kaiser` (which, I think, was built for this purpose), reduces the differences back to the original differences between `stats::varimax` and `GPArotation::Varimax`:

```
principal.Varimax.GPA.kaiser <- kaiser(f = principal.unrotated, rotate = "Varimax")
diff.statsvari.gpavar.bothkaiser <- unclass(principal.Varimax.GPA.kaiser$loadings - principal.varimax.stats$loadings)
mean(abs(diff.statsvari.gpavar.bothkaiser))
#> [1] 8.036863e-05
```

This is pretty much the same result, so I think **hypothesis confirmed**.

The bigger difference stemming from `psych::principal` is because of the different default values for `normalize`.

---

**Update**

The differences are also (again) much smaller for the respective rotation matrices (or whatever `Th` is):

```
principal.Varimax.GPA.kaiser$Th - principal.varimax.stats$rot.mat  # those differences are very small now, too
#>               [,1]         [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
#> [1,]  1.380279e-04 1.380042e-05 -2.214319e-04 -2.279170e-06
#> [2,]  9.631517e-05 2.391296e-05  1.531723e-04 -3.371868e-05
#> [3,]  1.758299e-04 7.917460e-05  6.788867e-05  1.099072e-04
#> [4,] -9.548010e-05 6.500162e-05 -1.679753e-05 -5.213475e-05
```